# max date for multiple id using different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables (SQL Server 2008 R2):

### Table 1

```
ID  Date  
123 20-08-2011  
123 20-08-2011  
234 30-09-2012
```

### Table 2

```
ID  Centre  ChangeDate      
123 987     16-08-11    
123 568     28-05-10
234 456     14-09-12
```

### Table 3

```
Centre  Centre_Name 
987     test1
568     test2
456     test3
```

I would like to make a query which joins all columns and only selects the Centre with the maximum ChangeDate. Thus, the following table should be returned:

```
ID      Date        Centre      ChangeDate  Centre_Name     
123     20-08-11    987         16-08-11    test1
123     20-08-11    987         16-08-11    test1
234     30-09-12    456         14-09-12    test3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There should be multiple ways of achieving your results. One way is by using a row_number() partitioned by your [Id] column (or [Id] and [Centre] if you want the Id/Centre combinations with the highest [ChangeDate]). This will yield unique results, and wouldn't fit your desired result as described in your answer (my question would be: why would you want duplicated answers?). The other method is using a subquery to retrieve the maximum changedate from Table 2 per Id, and subsequently joining that result tot Table 2 for a second time.

```
declare @table1 table ([Id] INT, [Date] date)
declare @table2 table ([Id] INT, [Centre] int, [ChangeDate] date)
declare @table3 table ([Centre] int, [Centre_Name] varchar(25))

insert into @table1 values (123,'2011-08-20'),(123,'2011-08-20'),(234,'2012-09-30')
insert into @table2 values (123,987,'2011-08-16'),(123,568,'2010-05-28'),(234,456,'2012-09-14')
insert into @table3 values (987,'test1'),(568,'test2'),(456,'test3')
```

Method 1: using row_number()

```
select *
from (
 select t1.[Id],t1.[Date],t2.[Centre],t2.[ChangeDate],t3.[Centre_Name]
 , rn=row_number() over (partition by t2.[Id]/*, t2.[Centre]*/ order by t2.[ChangeDate] desc)
 from   @table1 t1
 join   @table2 t2 on t2.Id = t1.Id 
 join   @table3 t3 on t3.Centre=t2.Centre
) x where x.rn=1
```

Method 2: using a subquery to retrieve the maximum [ChangeDate] per [Id]

```
select  t1.[Id],t1.[Date],t2.[Centre],t2.[ChangeDate],t3.[Centre_Name]
from    @table1 t1
join    (select Id, maxChangeDate=max(ChangeDate) from @table2 group by Id ) t2_maxChangeDate on t1.[Id]=t2_maxChangeDate.[Id]
join    @table2 t2 on t2.[Id]=t2_maxChangeDate.[Id] and t2.[ChangeDate]=t2_maxChangeDate.[maxChangeDate]
join    @table3 t3 on t3.[Centre] = t2.[Centre]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` :

```
select t1.*, tt.*
from table1 t1 cross apply
    ( select top (1) t2.Centre, t2.ChangeDate, t3.Centre_Name   
      from table2 t2 inner join
           table3 t3
           on t3.Centre = t2.Centre
      where t2.id = t1.id
      order by t2.ChangeDate desc
    ) tt;
```